# How to express the expected value of revenue w/ reserve price in 2nd price auction?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Breifly speaking, the problem comes from setting a reserve price in 2nd price auction, where w/o a reserve price $a_t$, the winner pays the 2nd highest bid $b_t$. But w/ a reserve price, the winner pays
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
a_t,& \text{if } a_t > b_t \\
b_t,& \text{if } a_t\leq b_t \\
0,& \text{if } a_t \text{ is higher than any bid}
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

The question is what the expected value $\mathbb{E}[r_t]$ is after setting a reserve price $a_t$ at every time step, given that $b_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Although I don't know how to derive probability of above 3 cases, I can give the following example: 1) if $a_t=1000$ then $pr(r_t=0)=1$ because $a_t$ is too high; 2) if $a_t=0$ then $p_r(r_t=b_t)=1$.

Shall I use cdf of $b_t$ and $a_t$ to derive the probabilities of each case?

Thanks!

Comment: How can $b_t$ be normally distributed if it is known to be larger than $a_t$, which we can choose any way we like? And no, I don't think your question can be answered the way it is right now. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @StephanKolassa The idea is at every time step we observe a $r_t$ which falls into one of these 3 cases. If it's $r_t>a_t$ then we know this $r_t$ is drawn from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: @StephanKolassa The problem is, for any of 3 cases the expected value is known, $a_t$, $0$, $\mu$, respectively. However the probability of falling into any category is unknown. I wonder if the following is feasible: we choose $a_t$ with a 95% confidence that $r_t=a_t$ then $\mathbb{E}[r_t]=a_t*0.95+\mu*0.025+0*0.025$? I'm not sure but sounds suspicious.

Comment: @Shuaiyuancn:, What do you mean the probability of each outcome type is unknown? Does it change over time? If not, then you can infer the probabilities by observing a large number of outcomes. Your expression in the comment above is correct in spirit, so long as your corresponding probabilities are correct (0.95, 0.025, 0.025) but I have no way of knowing whether they are or not.

Comment: @jerad The concern for the equation in my above comment is that "95%" is a confidence level of $r_t=a_t$, not the true probability. Using it in expected value equation seems suspicious.

Comment: @jerad Meanwhile, the probability of each outcome type is unknown and is changing based on $a_t$ we set in the beginning of every time step. For example, if we choose $a_t=1000$ it's almost certain that $r_t=0$ (let's say it's probability is 1); if we choose $a_t=0$ then it's almost certain that $r_t=b_t$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand what the underlying model is for your problem, and I'm not familiar with second-price auctions. It sounds like you know how to write the expectation of a random variable, so I suggest you think through exactly what the generating model is. In other words write out exactly what the dependencies are and if you still can't figure out the expression for the expectation then edit your question to incorporate all of the dependencies in your generating model and we'll help out.